# how Flash and C# communicate?

Tags: c#-3.0, flash-cs3

i need some help in making a C# application that embed's a flash .swf file
and what i want is to feed some data to it.

in html is like this

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase=
    "http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
    width="625" height="100%" id="flash" name="flash" align="">
      <param name="movie" value="http://www.mysite.com/flash/home.swf">
      <param name="loop" value="false">
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
      <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
      <param name="menu" value="false">
      <param name="quality" value="high">
      <param name="devicefont" value="true">
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
      <param name="FlashVars" value=
      "sid=5005405F&amp;data2=222&amp;data3=443&amp;data4=custom">
      <embed src="http://www.mysite.com/flash/home.swf" loop="false" menu=
      "false" allowscriptaccess="always" allownetworking="all" quality="high"
      devicefont="true" bgcolor="white" width="625" height="100%" name="flash"
      id="flash" align="" swliveconnect="true" type=
      "application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage=
      "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" flashvars=
      "sid=5005405F&amp;data2=222&amp;data3=443&amp;my_id=dunno&amp;data4=dinos&amp;cs_version=0">
```

what i want is to know how can i feed that data in C#

till now i can only load the .swf file when my app start's up

```
playerax.LoadMovie(0, Application.StartupPath + "\\home.swf");
playerax.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial:

[Flash tutorial - How to send data to ASP.NET and read the answer](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-96-Flash%20tutorial%20-%20How%20to%20send%20data%20to%20ASP.NET%20and%20read%20the%20answer)

Answer (score 0):

axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars = "auto_play=true&channel=adventuretimed&start_volume=25";